# Michelson interfermetory point source types of fringes?

Tags: optics

When we illuminate a Michelson interferometer with a point source with the mirrors at $0$ separation and with an angle between them, I have read we get linear fringes at infinity. Is it also true (like with an extended source) that we get linear fringes at the mirrors and what can we say about the shape of the fringes between these points? Does any of this depend on how large or small the angle between the mirrors is?

**EDIT**

Just to  clarify things, the main question I am asking is:

Given the 'wedge' configuration of mirrors in a Michelson interferometer do we get *linear* fringes both at infinity and at the mirrors or just at infinity?

**EDIT 2**

I have found this [source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UfztNNnSFckC&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=newton%20rings%20with%20a%20point%20source&source=bl&ots=l8WHLiIp15&sig=HBHe8bEmAAsShk_p9RGhlF0RYvY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM3Zi5osPLAhVD6xQKHRJbD7wQ6AEINDAF#v=onepage&q=newton%20rings%20with%20a%20point%20source&f=false) (link to google books), which explains why we need an extended source to see Newton rings and why we can't use just a point source. Would I be correct in saying that this reasoning is also true for the Michelson interferometer?

Answer (score 2):

Interferometers rely on division of amplitude, when most other interference devices (Young double slit, Fresnel mirrors, Fresnel double prism, Billet double lens, Lloyd mirror...) rely on division of wavefront. Apart from this difference, the way they work is the same: from a single primary source, make two secondary coherent sources. As a consequence, the fringes you obtain with a Michelson interferometer are the same as those obtained with Fresnel mirrors.

Two coherent *monochromatic*, *point* sources give fringes in *all space* with hyperboloid geometry, as a result of constant optical path difference $AM-BM=pλ$. The $p=0$ fringe is a plane in space (which intersects the screen along a straight line) for any $λ$; it is the only fringe independent of $λ$.

If the source is polychromatic, the resulting fringes are the sum of the fringes made by each monochromatic radiation in its spectrum. Fringes will blur each other, except the $p=0$ one. Hence, with a polychromatic (e.g. "continuous" white) source, you typically get a white, straight, $p=0$ fringe surrounded by a few *nearly* straight, coloured fringes, where "nearly" is theoretical, because practically the screen is too small to observe any curvature.

Always think of an interference pattern as the intersection of 3D fringes with the screen plane. With extended sources, the fringes are localized in space, so you can see a pattern only if the screen is in the appropriate region. With monochromatic point sources, the fringes are not localized, you can see a pattern wherever the screen is. With polychromatic point sources, the $p=0$ fringe is an infinite plane, you can see a straight pattern if and wherever the screen plane intersects it.

Side note: the circular fringes of equal inclination are simply the intersection of the hyperboloids with a screen perpendicular to their axis of symmetry.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. So if I was to focus on the mirrors when using a point source, I would see fringes and they would be hyperbolic rather then straight as in the case of an extended source??

Comment: Strictly speaking, they are not straight. But close to $p=0$ the hyperbolas have very small curvature.

Comment: Do you by any chance know any sources where I could read up on this in more detail?

Comment: Unfortunately no, at least in English (I'm French). I know only one very valuable book on optics in English, Hecht's *Optics*, but I don't know if and how it deals with this.

Answer (score -1):

There are two types of interference fringes:

- fringes of equal thickness which you obtain with an extended source
  and the mirrors inclined to one other.  These are the type of fringes you get with wedges and Newton's rings.  These fringes are localised in the wedge so you need to focus in the region of the wedge to see them.  These are like contour lines.
- fringes of equal inclination which you obtain by having a point
  source of light and the mirrors "parallel" to one another and this is the type you are referring to.  These fringes are localised at infinity so you need to focus the light coming from the interferometer with a lens (could be your eye) to be able to see them.

[More here](http://physics111.lib.berkeley.edu/Physics111/Reprints/ATM/04-Interference.pdf)

Comment: Hi I am talking about the case where we have a wedge and a point source, which you don't seem to cover in this answer.

Comment: If you use the apparatus an get fringes of equal inclination and then start moving one of the mirrors so that they are longer parallel you will get curved wedge type fringes which is a combination of the two "types" of fringe.  I do not think that there is a name for these "intermediate" type fringes.

Comment: I am not sure you still understand, see my edit above. I am talking about the **exact** same experimental setup as you have with an extended source for fringes of equal thickness, the only difference been you use a point source instead of an extended source.

Comment: Thank you.  Your note has clarified what you were asking.  I have stated what you see whilst you are changing from one situation to another.  So you will go from seeing rings then probably parts of something which are sort of ellipse id and hence my comment of curved wedge type fringes.  What I have not done is drawn a diagram to show the rays coming out of the arrangement to suggest where the fringes are localised and also to see where the fringes will be visible.